# Flutter : How to destroy all the API call (Future and Stream) when dispose a page

Tags: flutter

Switching bottom navigation bar faster from **Tab1** to **Tab2**. When switching to **Tab2** while the tab 1 API call is still running, the log file still display the result from **Tab1** API call when I'm inside **Tab2**. So what I want to do now is whenever I dispose a page it will dispose everything.

I've tried **CancelableOperation.fromFuture** method and I put the **CancelableOperation cancel** inside dispose function, the log file show **The method 'cancel' was called on null**.

```
CancelableOperation cancellableOperation = CancelableOperation.fromFuture(
      Future.value(await getApiData()),
      onCancel: () =>
          {debugPrint('onCancel')},
    );
```

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    cancellableOperation.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

```
I/flutter ( 9421): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'cancel' was called on null.
```

Any idea how to resolve this or any better solution ?